# OpenCV boundingRect output

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and Python and I made a program that finds contours with area that is above 500 and saves them into a new image I used boundingRect as advised on the internet, it runs and does the job well but I got a problem with an output of an image. It seems that noises near beside the region of interest are also saved. As you can see in the image below, there are some tiny shapes near beside the ROI. The output is good for other images its just that I want to get rid of noises like this. Is there a way to remove those kind of noises in the output?

Here is the output of the program I made:
[image: output or the new image]

Here is the input image:

[image]

Comment: can you post your input image?

Comment: oh yeah, sure I'll edit the post

Comment: You only want to remove the small contours from the black and white image?

Comment: Yes, if possible

Comment: If you threshold properly, followed by erosion you will not have to worry about these small unwanted blobs.

Comment: yeah, I tried doing that but it affected the other images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hide with contouring

This solution uses `cv2.drawContours()` to simply draw black contours over the noise. I ran the black and white sample image through a few iterations of dilation, filtered contours by area, and then drew black contour lines over the noise. I used the threshold feature because there turned out to be a good bit of minuscule noise in what initially appeared to be a simple black and white image.

#### Input:

[image]

#### Code:

```
import cv2

thresh_value = 10
img = cv2.imread("cells_BW.jpg")
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
dilation = cv2.dilate(img,(3,3),iterations = 3)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(T, thresh) = cv2.threshold(img_gray, thresh_value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = [i for i in contours if cv2.contourArea(i) < 5000]
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,0,0), 10, lineType=8)

cv2.imwrite("cells_BW_CLEAN.jpg", img)
```

#### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There could be several solutions depends on the assumption on the input data.

**Probable Methods**

1. If the ROI has a significantly different color than others,

   1-1. You can threshold the input image using RGB before finding the contour.
2. If the area of the object you want to find is significantly bigger that others,

   2-1. Fill the holes like [this example](https://www.learnopencv.com/filling-holes-in-an-image-using-opencv-python-c/)

   2-2. Calculate the size of the blobs, and exclude all the blobs except the largest one ([example to calculate the size of blobs](http://nghiaho.com/uploads/code/opencv_connected_component/blob.cpp)).

If there has intersection point between the contours of multiple objects, Method 2 surely fail to segment the region of single cell.