# OpenCV boundingRect to detect rectangle?

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to crop a rectangle in an image. I have a PDF of a form (which I've converted to an image) which looks similar to this [here](https://img.yumpu.com/16772683/1/500x640/dd-form-2585-repatriation-processing-center-processing-sheet-.jpg). I want to crop to the large rectangle (not each individual rectangle) so my output image is just the large rectangle and every contained within.

I am trying to eventually extract out the information contained within the large rectangle but my first step is I need to crop around the rectangle; my actual image has some text at the top of the rectangle as well as text below like in the example image. I attempted to use the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127776/opencv-boundingrect-output) but the output image it produced was no different from the original and did not crop around the rectangle.

```
thresh_value = 10
img = cv2.medianBlur(img_raw, 5)
dilation = cv2.dilate(img,(3,3),iterations = 3)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(T, thresh) = cv2.threshold(img_gray, thresh_value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = [i for i in contours if cv2.contourArea(i) < 5000]
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,0,0), 10, lineType=8)

cv2.imwrite("cropped_img.jpg", img)
```

The original code on the line where you define contours and hierarchy was `_, contours, hierarchy =` but I received an error saying `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`.

I did use the `boundingRect` function to remove whitespace (as seen in the code block below) and I think this is the most promising but I'm not totally clear on how to tweak this to instead of looking for text, look for the rectangle.

```
gray = 255*(img_raw < 128).astype(np.uint8)
coords = cv2.findNonZero(gray)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(coords)
processed_image = img_raw[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following to identify the rectangle and the third largest contour by area turned out to be the bottom big box:

```
img = cv2.imread("form.jpg")

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(T, thresh) = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
cv2.drawContours(img, [sorted_contours[2]], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

To more concretely answer you question, to crop the image, you have to get the properties of the bounding rectangle and crop the original image:

```
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(sorted_contours[2])
cropped_image = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
```

[image: Here is what I got as a result]